# How to create a file format for a custom application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdf

I currently have an application written in C#, which performs some calculations on electrical lines sag and tensions.

The program has only the option of exporting a .doc file, or printing to PDF. As it stands, I cannot save it into a format that allows me to change any data, as it is already in word, or pdf.

i need to setup an intermediary file format, that allows editing of the file, while retaining the ability to export the project file to Word or PDF.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: XML is a common choice due to its wide support and ease of editing

Comment: Do you have the source code? 

If so, you can add the output on any format you want. Even a simple TXT file.

If you don't have the source code, than you can't do anything, but asks the developer to do so.

Comment: This is basically a choice to *serialize* data. Extension of file can be up to you (`.ELST` - electrical lines sag and tensions), but internally it is something what you are able to save/load. Can be text (ini-alike? token-based? csv-like?), xml or something binary. Which one to choose depends on requirements: should data be editable by human, protection level, etc. For performance and size check [Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). To add security you can put protobuf data into binary container with some signature.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define your own binary file format. How to define it depends on the data to store and this is up to you.

Or you can use XML file format. Of course again you'll have to define what to write in which structure to the file. It might be a good idea to provide your own DTD.

Comment: @AlexK. Good point, I changed my answer so hopefully it gets clearer.